# Sorting a column alphabetically with cells connected

Tags: vba, excel

My goal is to first hide some columns (`A:F`) in my worksheet and second to sort the remaining columns alphabetically by a certain one (`AT`). This macro should work on every worksheet in my workbook. This is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub HideSort()
Dim ws As Worksheet
' loop through all worksheets
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
' hide columns
ws.Columns("A:F").Hidden = True
' sort alphabetically
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim clmn As String
Dim area As String
area = "A4:FJ5000"
clmn = "AT"
ws.Range(area).Sort _
Key1:=ws.Range(clmn & "1"), Order1:=xlDescending, _
Header:=xlGuess, MatchCase:=False, _
Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Next ws
End Sub
```

The hiding part works perfect. But running together with the sorting part I get a runtime error '1004': All connected cells must have the same size.

Yes I have connected cells in my worksheet, but only the headers in the first two rows. That's why I only want the sorting from the 4th row downwards `A4:FJ5000`.

Other connected cells do not exist as I already checked. So where is my mistake here? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try with area = "A:FJ" ?

Comment: Replace `Key:=ws.Range(clmn & "1")` with `Key:=ws.Range(clmn & "4:" & clmn & "5000")`?

Comment: @JAnandBoss Thanks. I tried what you mentioned but no difference

Comment: @trincot Thanks but still the same error. Debugging marks this area `ws.Range(area).Sort _
Key1:=ws.Range(clmn & "1"), Order1:=xlDescending, _
Header:=xlGuess, MatchCase:=False, _
Orientation:=xlTopToBottom`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Maybe best to reduce the problem to a very small range, eliminating step by step until the problem no longer occurs, which means you eliminated too much. Then post some information of your findings.

Comment: Are you able to sort a range like that with a key that doesn't exist in that range??

Comment: @dwirony Yes, I tried it on another charts with connected header cells and different cell sizes...works perfectly with the exact same macro. I don't get it!

Comment: What does it actually exactly mean that all the connected cells have to have the same size?? Because I created an example chart where I changed cell hight and width and connected different numbers of cells and the macro works there. So what does the error really mean??